# gulp-imagemin doesn't respect series()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gulp

I have the following `gulp` task;

```
function media(cb) {
    src('private/media/**')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            "silent": true
        }))
        .pipe(dest('public/media'));
    cb();
}
```

When i try to run `gulp build` for;

```
exports.build = series(clean, parallel(html, media, javascript, css));
```

I get the message `Finished 'media' after 18 ms` the cursor will then blink for a bit while `gulp-imagemin` finishes and then the process quits. To know that `gulp-imagemin` is responsible as I have removed the `silent` flag and get output from `gulp-imagemin` just before the process quits.

This is a problem because later in the `gulp` file I use `browserSync` and the images haven't finished processing before the browser loads it up.

How can I tell the `media` task to wait for the asyncronous `gulp-imagemin` task to finish before saying that it is done to gulp and that it should move on?

Comment: Well you're calling `cb` immediately without waiting for the piping to be completed?!

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Is there any difference if you use a `return src...` statement instead of the `cb()`?

Comment: @Mark the following error is returned `The following tasks did not complete: build, <parallel>, media. Did you forget to signal async completion?`

Comment: @glend https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts/#tasks. Like Mark said, just return the stream, and remove the `cb` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the comments suggested, the answer was;

```
function media() {
    return src('private/media/**')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            "silent": true
        }))
        .pipe(dest('public/media'));
}
```